# Set the attribute value of one table as attribute name of another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, attributes, records

Is there any way to set the values of a table as the attribute names of another table?
For example: I have a table

```
Symptoms (Id, SymptomName)
```

Symptoms has records like

```
1, Fever
2, Cough
3, Headache
4, Nausea
```

Now I want to create a table with struct

```
Casebase(id, Fever, Cough, Headache, Nausea)
```

Can anyone guide me that whether it is possible and how.

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL for this. But why do you want to do something like this in the first place?

Comment: Lookup pivot queries. No need to create a table like that when you can do it in a query.

Comment: In the Casebase table I have to store records in 0/1 format. There are other tables which are linked. So this is the requirement of my work